# How join two query by removing inner query name in MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have two tables. One table has floor number(tb_FloorNumber.FloorNumber. records :For example 1 to 15) and another table which has Floor number and User_Id column(tb_Emp_Master.FloorNumber, tb_Emp_Master.User_Id). I want to bring all the records from tb_FloorNumber and only the records from tb_Emp_Master with the condition (User_Id = "fat35108").

[image]

I know I can do this with two queries like this :
Query 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb_Emp_Master.FloorNumber
FROM tb_Emp_Master
WHERE (((tb_Emp_Master.User_Id)="fat35108"));
```

Query2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb_FloorNumber.FloorNumber, Query1.FloorNumber
FROM tb_FloorNumber LEFT JOIN Query1 ON tb_FloorNumber.FloorNumber = Query1.FloorNumber;
```

But I want to write this query with sing query instead of using Query1 inside the Query 2

I have tried like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb_FloorNumber.FloorNumber, tb_Emp_Master.FloorNumber
FROM tb_FloorNumber LEFT JOIN tb_Emp_Master ON tb_FloorNumber.FloorNumber = tb_Emp_Master.FloorNumber
WHERE (((tb_Emp_Master.User_Id)="fat35108"));
```

But it brings only one record (For instance 8)

Please help me how to write this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the condition:

```
tb_Emp_Master.User_Id = "fat35108"
```

in the `WHERE` clause, then you actually get an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN` because you filter only the matched rows from `tb_Emp_Master`.
Use `tb_Emp_Master` in the `LEFT JOIN` instead of `Query1` and set the condition in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  tb_FloorNumber.FloorNumber, 
  tb_Emp_Master.FloorNumber
FROM tb_FloorNumber LEFT JOIN tb_Emp_Master 
ON tb_FloorNumber.FloorNumber = tb_Emp_Master.FloorNumber AND tb_Emp_Master.User_Id = "fat35108";
```

I don't know why you need `DISTINCT` so I use it too.